# MaterializeCSS : two lines in a button

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS, and I'd like to be able to enable long texts in a button to appear on 2 lines instead of being truncated.

Here is a clear example :
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgy6j0k5/2/)

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>juste change the panel size to see what i'm talking about</a>
```

I already tried to change the "line-height" property of the btn class. This works quite well, but then if the screen is large enough for the content to be displayed on one line, the text and icon will stick at the top of the button, yet i would like these to be vertically centered.

Is there a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: works fine in Opera, not going to 2 lines.
What browser is this happening for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply this style to override the existing styling:

```
.btn.waves-effect {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Your example, updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/kgy6j0k5/3/

**Edit: with icon centered vertically**

```
.btn.waves-effect {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.btn.waves-effect .material-icons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Really nice ! It works as expected. May I abuse and ask if it's possible to vertically center the icon on the right ? I think the code is not designed to serve that purpose, but we never know. Nevertheless, many thanks for your help !

Comment: Yup, it can be done. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution that worked for me :

```
height:auto !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove height from here:

```
.btn, .btn-large, .btn-flat {
    height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, but the problem is that each line will then be 36px height, which is not pretty... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: i say "remove" height

Comment: I know, but "line-height" remains at 36px, sorry I wasn't clear enough :)